# Why is numpy.spacing(0) giving me an impossible number?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, floating-point, ieee-754

I am working on Python. I have tried numpy.spacing(0) and got 4.9406564584124654e-324, which is significantly smaller than finfo(float).tiny = 2.2250738585072014e-308

How is it possible?

I have found no answer on the web, and this number is of course impossible in terms of the floating point standard.

Comment: What on earth makes you think “this number is … impossible in terms of the floating point standard”?  IEEE-754 very clearly requires that it exist.

Comment: @StephenCanon to be fair, `sys.float_info.min` suggests otherwise (and subnormals are not the most widely publicised concept in the world).

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: The questioner is appealing to “the floating point standard” for their claim.  Perhaps naively, I expect them to have a passing familiarity with what it actually says if they’re going to cite it.

Answer (score 13):

Okay, so let's see what 4.94e-324 actually is:

```
>>> from math import log
>>> log(4.94e-324, 2)
-1074.0
```

And just to make sure:

```
>>> 2**-1074
5e-324
```

That's definitely less than the -1022 which is supposed to be the minimum exponent. In fact, it's **52** less than the minimum, which is the number of bits in the significand. Something interesting is going on here ...

What you've actually got there is a [subnormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) float, which is encoded with an exponent of zero (interpreted to mean the lowest actually-possible exponent), and relaxes the usual rule that the significand must start with a binary 1, allowing you to represent very small numbers at the cost of precision:

```
>>> (5e-324).hex()
'0x0.0000000000001p-1022'
```